# What are the main contributors to memory overload in NNs

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, batch-size

[In this article](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) they talk about computational considerations for convnets.

I used to think that the main bottleneck were the weights. They name:

- activations and gradients
- input data (like images)

Are activations meant as both the weights and the (single) function that operates?

Comment: Activations are the outputs from each layer. I think the reason they are significant is because of batching. You don't run 1 image through at a time, but 100, 1000, however many you can fit in memory at once. Whereas there is only one copy of the weights.

Comment: @user253751 interesting, yet you only need the L-1 output for the L layer, but probably all the outputs have to be held in memory before backpropagation..